# Evaluate $\iiint_E z\,{\rm d}v$, where $E$ is the region between the spheres $x ^2 + y ^2 + z ^2 = 1$ and $x ^2 + y ^2 + z ^2 = 3$ in the first octant

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

> Evaluate $$\iiint_E z \,{\rm d}v,$$ where $E$ is the region between the spheres $x ^2 + y ^2 + z ^2 = 1$ and $x ^2 + y ^2 + z ^2 = 3$ in the first octant.

Using cylindrical coordinates I got $r$ bounded by $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{2}$ and theta bounded by $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$. $$\iiint_E 1 \,{\rm d}v$$

Comment: draw the region of integration..then start thinking

Comment: Isn't $sqrt{3}$ instead of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @SalahFatima   I think both the spheres intersect when r = sqrt(2)

Comment: @noelsean Where does $\sqrt{2}$ comes from.

Comment: @SalahFatima Can you do it using cylindrical coordinates please?

Comment: @SalahFatima is right; moreover, the first bound is $1$ and not $0$ : $1 \leq r \leq \sqrt{3}$ because the equation of a 0-centered sphere is $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2.$

Comment: Moreover, you should use spherical coordinates, not cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: @noelsean The cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$ are not adequat in this case.

Comment: @SalahFatima If I did with cylindrical coordinates, can u tell me the bounds of z?

Comment: @noelsean $1$ and $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: @SalahFatima I am asking 'z' bounds not the  radius bounds

Comment: It is graphically evident that the top of a sphere of radius $r=\sqrt{3}$ is at $z=\sqrt{3}$ thus $0 \leq z  \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @noelsean In cylindrical, bounds of $z$ are $1$ and $\sqrt{3}$.!

Comment: @SalahFatima I am sorry but there was a typo in my question. Can you go over it now??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us use spherical coordinates

$$x=r\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$$

$$y=r\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)$$

$$z=r\cos(\phi)$$

with $$1\leq r \leq \sqrt{3}$$
$$0\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$0\leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$

then $$I=\int_1^{\sqrt{3}}r^3dr\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)d\phi$$

$$=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Notice that we added the Jaccobian
$$r^2\sin(\phi)$$

Comment: Can you do it using cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: @noelsean Is it correct now.